# What abilities change with Spider Form, Lesser?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I am looking at the *Spider Form, Lesser* spell which reads in part:

> As the transformation finishes, your skin hardens into a dark exoskeleton.
>   You take on the form and abilities of a Medium fiendish monstrous spider (MM 289). [..] See page 59 for details of the polymorph subschool.

Looking at the polymorph subschool it looks like I would take on all abilities of the new form (the fiendish spider) meaning my constitution modifier could change. Do I use this new modifier or do I "retain my own hit points" as is stated in the polymorph sub school?

Do all my abilities change or just strength dexterity and constitution as the polymorph spell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Drow of the Underdark* on page 59 presents a description of the polymorph subschool that synchs with the polymorph subschool description from page 320 of the premium edition *Player's Handbook* (2012). Both include a bullet saying, "The subject retains its own hit points."

The caster of the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell *lesser spiderform* [trans] (*DrU* 63) retains his own hit points (yet, of course, gains the 5 temporary hp the spell says the caster does), but the caster uses the [fiendish](http://dndsrd.net/monstersEtoF.html#fiendish-creature) [Medium monstrous spider](http://dndsrd.net/monstersVermin.html#monstrous-spider)'s Constitution 12 to determine, for instance, the caster's Fortitude saving throw bonus and his Concentration skill check modifier.

Further, like the spell *lesser spiderform* says, "You take on the form and abilities of a Medium fiendish monstrous spider…." While this *can* be read instead as *special* abilities rather than ability scores, this seems an unlikely reading given the limitations and level of the spell. Further, changing ability scores agrees with the description of the polymorph subschool: "The target of [the] spell takes on all the statistics… of an average member of the new form," and, "[T]he target’s normal statistics are effectively replaced by those of the new form."

So the caster assumes all the ability scores of the Medium fiendish monstrous spider—hence Str 11, Dex 17, Con 12, Int 3, Wis 10, Cha 2, the creature's Intelligence score raised to 3 by the template [fiendish](http://dndsrd.net/monstersEtoF.html#fiendish-creature).